How to stop the wallpaper animation after updating to iOS 17.5?
I just updated to iOS 17.5.1.  Since I got an iPhone X, I've been using the rainbow on black wallpaper that Apple includes for both my lockscreen and my apps.
However, going from 17.4 to 17.5, there is now a super annoying animation whenever I open the home screen from the lock screen or if I swipe down to check notifications.
How do I disable this new behavior?
I have had the "reduce motion" accessibility setting enabled since it was introduced (and really, I would've thought that should be enough to stop something like this).
